# Full screen div video like on Nexus 7 site

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

What is the best method to get a full screen background video (like on the nexus 7 site: http://www.google.com/nexus/7/)?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you already have an answer, but this may be what you're looking for:

http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/